# Why doesn't setting video element srcObject doesn't work inside Vue.js App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-video

Consider the following app (code simplified)

```
<div id="app">
<video id="my-vid" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

**JS**

I am setting `document.getElementById("my-vid").objectSrc = stream` media stream (after asking the user for the usual user media, etc...) in plain javascript (that is without any vue js property binding).

It doesn't work (browser not displaying media stream, but a console.log still shows a valid `MediaStream` object.

When i move the video element **outside** the VueJS app however, **it works !**

```
<div id="app">
</div>
<video id="my-vid" autoplay></video>
```

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the correct way is

```
document.getElementById("video").srcObject = stream
```

I used it this way and it works pretty well..

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <video id="videotag" autoplay></video>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "video",
  components: {},
  mounted() {
     navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        // Start video camera
        navigator.getUserMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: false
            },
            function (stream) {
              document.getElementById('videotag').srcObject = stream
            },
            function (error) {
              console.error(error)
            }
        )
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I indeed used "my-video" (ie. correct selector). I am also using adapter.js to normalize getUserMedia method.

Comment: This was it ! Its working when waiting for the "mounted" hook event. Why does vuejs delay the rendering of plain HTML elements on a web page ?

Comment: You video selector is "my-vid"

Comment: It was the autoplay that solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

In vue, you should never use `document.getElementById()`. Anything you can do with `document.getElementById()` you can do with `ref`. Try...

```
<div id="app">
   <video ref="myVid" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

then in your script, inside Vue...

```
var me = this;
// Start video camera
navigator.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: false
    },
    function (stream) {
        me.$refs.myVid.srcObject = stream
    },
    function (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
)
```

This is because DOM level id is scoped to the whole page (whole app). From inside your little component, you can't dictate what ids other components might use, and conflicts are possible. Ref only needs to be unique within your component.